# Rails: after redirect back retain input value that uses typeahead

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js, typeahead

I have the following search form:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: "get", id: "other-form"  do %>
<div class="input-group">
  <%= text_field_tag :address, params[:address], id:"address",
                     class: "address", placeholder: "Enter address"  %>
 <button class="btn btn-custom" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "search",
                     placeholder: "Enter keyword" %>
```

this is the autocomplete - typeahead action inside the a controller:

```
def autocomplete
  if params[:search].present?
  render json: Item.search(params[:search], {
    fields: ["title"],
    match: :word_start,
    limit: 10,
    load: false,
    misspellings: {below: 5}
  }).map(&:title).uniq
  else params[:search_other].present?
  render json: Item.search(params[:search], {
    fields: ["title"],
    match: :word_start,
    limit: 10,
    load: false,
    misspellings: {below: 5}
  }).map(&:title).uniq
  end
end
```

An this is the javascript for it:

```
<script>
var items = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/items/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH',
        wildcard: '%SEARCH'
    }
});

$('#search')
    .typeahead(null, {source: items})
    .on('typeahead:selected', function(e){
    })
</script>
```

The setup I'm after is: after a search and when I hit back, to retain all the previous values in the form. Currently when I hit the back, the address value appears but not the "enter the keyword" one. Now, if I get rid of this:

```
$('#search')
    .typeahead(null, {source: items})
    .on('typeahead:selected', function(e){
    })
```

The "enter the keyword" value appears after I hit the back, but that is not the setup I'm, after. Any ideas on how to implement this?